# WSO2 VFS transport process file that not complete

Tags: wso2, apache-commons-vfs

I write a vfs proxy to route files from one folder to another. But recently I'm facing a problem. 
The vfs transport seems to process a file that not yet completed (I copy a file to the source path), so for example I copy a 18mb file to the source path but when the file is copied just 1mb its already processed by the vfs transport. In the end, only that 1mb part of file is sent to the target path. 
So, how can I make my vfs proxy to wait the file to be copied completely then processed it?
My proxy look like this

```
<proxy name="XXX" transports="vfs" startOnLoad="true" trace="disable">
  <description/>
  <target>
     <inSequence>
        <log level="custom">
           <property name="File" value="Moved"/>
        </log>
     </inSequence>
  </target>
  <parameter name="transport.vfs.ActionAfterProcess">MOVE</parameter>
  <parameter name="transport.PollInterval">1</parameter>
  <parameter name="transport.vfs.FileURI">file:///SourcePath</parameter>
  <parameter name="transport.vfs.MoveAfterProcess">file:///TargetPath</parameter>
  <parameter name="transport.vfs.FileNamePattern">.*.*</parameter>
  <parameter name="transport.vfs.ContentType">text/plain</parameter>
```

Answer (score 0):

add this property and go through the wso2 docs for large file need to modify axis2 files streaming property

```
<property name="transport.vfs.Streaming" value="true" scope="default"/>
```

further assistance go for docs

```
http://docs.wso2.org/display/ESB480/VFS+Transport
```